# How to squeeze 3 `<include layout=` in one row?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image">

        <include layout="@layout/time_box"/>

        <include layout="@layout/time_box" />

        <include layout="@layout/time_box" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="enter your name"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

and this `xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#152"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="#120"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.07" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:text="--"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.88" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

and I want it to look eventually like:

[image]

what would you change in my positioning and sizing?

Answer (score 0):

Use layout weights.

`<include layout="@layout/time_box"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>`

Do this for each of the included views